# Identify This Connector (Polar Bear Water Distiller)

Tags: ac, connector, identification

I am building an automatic water drain for our water distiller. The water distiller is a [polar bear 26-D8](http://www.polarbearwater.com/). The company is basically out of business and is no help.

The distiller has two connectors on it, one for a constant 120V to power the automatic drain circuit and another one that is controlled by a float.

[image: Connector]

I would like to use the connectors that are there but I don't know what they are and I have been unsuccessful at finding them on google, mouser, digi-key, etc. so I was hoping someone here would recognize them.

[image: Measurements]

Above are two photos and dimensions I measured with a caliper. The only markings that I can see is 7A-125. It seems to be polarized by pin size as one is bigger than the other.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: AC Plug and socket?? please add a pictureof the counterpart of the connector?

Comment: I wish I had the counter part, I would just cut it off and use it. It is on the $500 auto drain they used to sell.

Comment: If there's 120V on that connector I'm not surprised they are out of business. Given the drawing you've made I'd get a hunk of Delrin, a length of brass rod, and start the lathe. It looks like that's what they did in the first place.

Comment: That's twice some one has told be to fire up the lathe (also posted in reddit). I guess that is what I will have to do as I have all the equipment needed.

Comment: Otherwise have you got access to the inside of it? May be able to retrofit a female IEC 60320 connector potentially with a little bit of metalwork.

Comment: That looks like the two-prong polarized connector many TVs used to use, for 120VAC.  Unpolarized variant here: <http://www.allelectronics.com/make-a-store/item/acs-6/2-con.-ac-rececptacle-for-cheater-cords/1.html>

Answer (score 1):

From what i could find Polar bear had a replacement kit that did away with that plug connector . The kit wired a full 6' cord into the machine and removed the connector all together .

Comment: While your answer is related, it unfortunately does not actually address the question asked. Since the company is out of business, obtaining the replacement kit is not a reliable solution. Can you provide any relevant information about the connector when it *is* present?

Comment: @user2943160 - the implication here seems to be that the company that designed that connector in ultimately designed it back out and selected an alternative scheme to offer as a retrofit, so perhaps the asker should consider making their own selection of something appropriate, *rather* than trying to match this.